# При считывании из файла в конце появляется "я"

Tags: c++

как можно пофиксить проблему с появлением символа "я" в конце?

```
void inputText(string& word) {
    ifstream fin;
    string inputfile;
    do
    {
        cout << "Введите название файла для ввода" << endl;
        cin >> inputfile;
        fin.open(inputfile + ".txt", ios::binary);  
    } while (!fin.is_open());
    while(!fin.eof())
        word += fin.get();
    fin.close();
}
```

Comment: Вы не проверяете `get()`, он возвращает eof вам